# Is there an option to copy the files from a Azure VM to multiple VM's in VMSS

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I am having a file in one of the VM in Azure. I want that file to be placed in all the VM's in VM Scale set.

I tried with multiple Azure CLI command as such az vmss run-command, but it provides an option to execute a command inside the VM's in VMSS.

I am expecting an option apart from scp or ssh, Since both the option would require more effort to copy the files, and also the client(Machine where the source file is residing) need to know the information about the VM's in VMSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way except for SCP or SSH is to mount the Azure File Share to the VMSS after you copy the file to the File Share. You can take a look at the example about [Azure Files template for VM scale sets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-azure-files-linux). So that all the virtual machines in the VMSS will share the files in the Azure File Share.